# Git diff/log -p without decoration

Tags: git

Hi I wish to run eslint on the files that have changed in recent commits.

```
git log -p
```

Gives me all the changes made but with extra decoration. 
I can remove the below content

```
diff --git a/apps....
--- file path
+++ file path
@@
```

but I want removed the "+" for added/modified - "removed" line from git itself to keep the code indentation intact.
Is there any way i can remove these +,-

I want to run a grunt task on this git log -p output then

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
git log -p --name-only
```

or

```
git log -p | sed 's/^\-\-\-//g' | sed 's/^\+\+\+//g'
```

Edit: added ^ to regex

Comment: git log -p --name-only will give names of the file. I want the actual changes made which i can feed to linter. +,- symbols in content will confuse the linter. I am save the output in a file